# Four-momentum of a photon emitted from an accretion disk

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, photons, momentum, accretion-disk

Consider a non-rotating compact object surrounded by a revolving accretion disk. A distant observer sees the disk in an edge-on position. The center of the disk may be taken as the origin of $r-\theta-\phi$ coordinate system. The accretion disk lies in the $\theta=\pi/2$ plane. The distant observer is located in the plane of the disk along $\phi=0$ direction. The geometry outside the disk is Schwarzschild. The accretion matter is assumed to revolve in circular orbits.

I want to understand how there exist two positions on the disk $(\phi=\pm\pi/2)$ from where if accretion matter emits light that is ultimately received by the observer, then the radial component of such a photon's four momentum must vanish ($p_r=0)$. This has reference to Hartle's book (page 248) and Hobson's book (page 241).

Comment: Don't have the books to hand, but are they discussing the radial component at the moment of emission?  In that case, it's just geometry for the path the the observer. The photon is moving tangent to the disk there.

Comment: Yes. They are discussing at the moment of emission. What you said is right and I realized it later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question can be closed with the answer given by Bob Jacobsen (see comments): the photon is moving tangent to the accretion disk so the variation of the radial component $ p^r $ is zero.

Best regards.